# Minimum system requirement for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the minimum system requirement for ROS?
I want to install ROS on TS-7260 and it has the following configuration:
200Mhz ARM9 CPU with MMU
32 MB on-board NAND flash (128 MB optional)
32 MB SDRAM (64 or 128 MB optional)
I am booting it with Debian OS and want to install ROS over it . So will it work well on it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197934/minimum-system-requirement-for-ros/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is a large federated ecosystem. You likely can get some of the core ROS packages installed on that system, but with your limited storage the number of packages you will be able to install will be small.

Likewise with a limited CPU you will be able to use ROS components, but you will be limited in how much data processing you can do by the CPU.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-03-29**:
Note that this is a frequently asked question w/o a concrete answer: https://www.google.com/search?q=ros+minimum+system+requirements+site:answers.ros.org